# Dalle3 request in Next.js 14 server actions leading to FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT on vercel

Tags: next.js13, vercel, openai-api, edge-function

I am hosting my next 14 app on Vercel. My app generates images using the dalle3 api and stores them into a firebase firestore. It all works correctly on my dev server but gets a FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT on my vercel-hosted production app.

Let me first explain more what I am trying to do. Upon a button click, a user can create a movie character with some info they specify. This all gets put into a firebase DB. A picture is then automatically generated for that character using Dalle. Here is some basic code to demonstrate that onClick handler:

```js
async function handleCreateCharacter() {
    await addNewCharacterToFirestore(movieId, newCharacterInfo);
    // generate picture in background - since dalle takes ~15 seconds to generate image
    generatePictureForCharacter(movieId, newCharacterInfo);
  }
```

I generate the picture using dalle in the background instead of awaiting it since it takes a while and I want the user to be able to view other parts of the website while the character is being generated. `generatePictureForCharacter` is a function defined in a file with the `"use server"` directive since open AI only allows you to use its api on the server.  `generatePictureForCharacter` simply creates the image and then updates the firestore document for that character with the generated image.

I've tried to move this `generatePictureForCharacter` logic into an api `POST` route at `/api/generate_character_image/route.ts` that uses the edge runtime to try to get around the FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT, but the problem is that the firebase sdk uses some require statements which the edge runtime can't handle. So, I tried to then make an `/api/generate_image/route.ts` api `POST` route in which I *only* generate the image and return it in the response and fetch that inside my original `generatePictureForCharacter` server action method, but then I got a `Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render but no message was provided`